# Compile user subroutine only once when running consecutive jobs in Abaqus

Tags: python, compilation, fortran, subroutine, abaqus

I have a script written in Python which calibrates material parameters based on the output of the last job, that is, it runs many jobs in Abaqus consecutively until an error is small enough.

I use a Fortran subroutine which compiles before each job.

The problem is that for each job I submit, the user subroutine compiles. Even though the input parameters are different from the last job the user subroutine does not have to be compiled again. Compilation of the subroutine takes about 80% of the time of running a job.

**How can I specify to only compile the user subroutine ONCE and use it for all consecutive runs?**

The following is snippets of relevant code written in Python. I execute my script by typing

```
abaqus cae nogui=script.py
```

in a terminal. The code uses the Abaqus scripting interface.

Creating a job:

```
mdb.Job(name=self.jobName, model='Model-1', description='', type=ANALYSIS, 
        atTime=None, waitMinutes=0, waitHours=0, queue=None, memory=90, 
        memoryUnits=PERCENTAGE, getMemoryFromAnalysis=True, 
        explicitPrecision=SINGLE, nodalOutputPrecision=SINGLE, echoPrint=OFF, 
        modelPrint=OFF, contactPrint=OFF, historyPrint=OFF,
        userSubroutine=self.userSubroutinePath, 
        scratch='', resultsFormat=ODB, multiprocessingMode=DEFAULT, numCpus=1, 
        numGPUs=0)
```

Submit and wait for job completion:

```
mdb.jobs[self.jobName].submit(consistencyChecking=OFF)
mdb.jobs[self.jobName].waitForCompletion()
```

This code is run each time I run a consecutive job with data from the previous run.

The compiler is Intel 64 Fortran Compiler XE, Version 15.0.0.090 Build 20140723.

Comment: Look in the manual for  `abaqus make`

Comment: @agentp Yes, I use the command 'abaqus make library=umat.f' but I get a prompt stating 'Missing required argument: job=<name>', which arguably makes no sense since according to the manual I can use 'abaqus make {job=<name> OR library=<name.f>}'. Thanks

Comment: my guess would be your "abaqus" command is really a script that is trying to do some preprocessing before passing your arguments to the real abaqus command. Try to determine the actual full path to the abaqus executable and run that.

Comment: @agentp Thank you for you suggestion. I ran the command now as follows '/path/abaqus make library=umat.f' and it tried starting the compilation as opposed to earlier, so that's a step in the right dorection. However, i get a command line error that says 'sh: ifort: command not found'. I guess there's a problem in my .env file then. I have specified the compile_fortran variable with options and when compiling while running a job i am able to compile subroutines on the fly. Thanks

Comment: well, if i was right about the script thing, that script might be putting ifort on your path..  It cant be too hard to figure out the path for ifort and add it to your environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By entering

```
module add abaqus
module add intel
module add gcc
```

I *then* was allowed to enter

```
abaqus make library=usub.f
```

which would compile the subroutine.

Comment: for others who might have this problem, this answer is very system specific.

Comment: @agentp Yes, I might add that I'm running all this on a Gridcore Gompute cluster running CentOS 6.7

Answer (score 0):

For windows platforms:

First, create a ".dll" file using "abaqus make library" command. You could find it in your ABAQUS directory.

Second, edit the environment file (e.g. "abaqus_v6") by adding the following line

usub_dir_lib="xxx"

where xxx is the rout to the ".dll" file (here, the ABAQUS directory).

Now, you are ready to execute your Python code